# How group elements in LINQ to get result like Facebook messages

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have Document class:

```
public class Document
{
        public int FromCompanyId { get; set; }
        public int ToCompanyId { get; set; }
        public string DocumentText { get; set; }
}
```

When any Company sends Document to others, I saved their `Id`'s. Shortly I have many pairs of ID's:

```
1, 2  //  Company which has Id=1 sent document to Company which has Id=2.
1, 3  //  Company which has Id=1 sent document to Company which has Id=3.
4, 3  //  Company which has Id=4 sent document to Company which has Id=3 etc.
2, 1  
4, 3  
4, 5  
5, 4  
5, 5  
4, 5  
3, 1
```

I want to make any Company manage **only its own** documents. Sent and Received. How can I get documents by Company Id? Or anybody can give another advice.

So, when `id = ToCompanyId` (any Company sent document to this Company) I want to group by `FromCompanyId` and when `id = FromCompanyId` (this Company sent document to other Company) I want to group by `ToCompanyId`.

This looks like facebook messages. When I cross my messages, I see my all dialogues **by Id of other users**. In my application I want to see documents by Id of other companies.

This works right only `id = FromCompanyId`.

```
GetDocumentsByCompanyId(int Id)
{
...
var myDocs= MyDatabaseContext.Documents.Where(e => e.FromCompanyId == Id|| e.ToCompanyId == Id);

var docGroups = from m in myDocs
                group m by m.ToCompanyId
                into g select new { ToCompanyIdKey = g.Key, betweenDocs = g };
...

}
```

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: why don't you use 2 queries; one fetching received documents and the other fetching sent documents? are you planning to display all sent and received documents in one list?

Comment: Yes, I want to show documents like facebook messages. when click other company's name, to show between documents. For this I want to collect all documents and send it to view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code.
It simply uses the conditional operator to find out which is the ID of the other company. This information is than used to group the documents.

```
var myDocs = MyDatabaseContext.Documents
                              .Where(e => e.FromCompanyId == Id ||
                                          e.ToCompanyId == Id)
                              .Select(x => new { OtherCompanyId
                                                   = (x.FromCompanyId == Id) ? 
                                                      x.ToCompanyId : 
                                                      x.FromCompanyId,
                                                 Document = x });

var docGroups = from m in myDocs
                group m by m.OtherCompanyId into g
                select new { ToCompanyIdKey = g.Key,
                             BetweenDocs = g.Select(x => x.Document) };
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking this from the morning